# Converting uploaded audio files to mp3 using PHP/ffmpeg

Tags: php, audio, ffmpeg

I have limited experience of using PHP, but having done some searching around it would seem that it is possible to convert audio files that are uploaded through a web page to mp3 using ffmpeg. The audio files would be uploaded using the Uploadify script to subfolders that are named according to the user's login.

I would need the PHP script to be able to process all audio files that are either not in MP3 format, or are in MP3 format but greater than 192kbps, deleting the original file after the conversion. Am I right in thinking that this could be achieved using PHP, and if so, can anyone get me started with some code, or a link to a webpage with some code?

Also, I am currently using Hostpapa for hosting my website, and I understand that they don't include ffmpeg, and also don't allow ssh. I read on one website that I could still install a compiled version of ffmpeg on a shared server, but I am not sure if this means that it would work on Hostpapa, or whether I would need to change my host to get ffmpeg working.

Any advice on any of this would be welcome!

Thanks,

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would basically run ffmpeg from PHP or use an PHP-API for ffmpeg like [this](http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/).
If you cannot access the server via ssh and they do not have ffmpeg installed, it might be possible to use a precompiled binary, but you might also not be allowed to run commands from PHP or install software.

Comment: Thanks.  I have now switched to Cirtex hosting, which includes ffmpeg and ffmpeg-PHP. I am now wondering how to write a script to convert files uploaded to a specific directory to MP3, as per the original question above.  I am wondering if you could help with this or point me to a tutorial?  Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0):

Your best bet is to contact the host. If they cannot support ffmpeg you will need a new host. When choosing the host, ask them before you sign up if they can support ffmpeg and provide you with SSH access or a jail shell.

Comment: Thanks.  I have now switched to Cirtex hosting, which includes ffmpeg and ffmpeg-PHP. I am now wondering how to write a script to convert files uploaded to a specific directory to MP3, as per the original question above.  I am wondering if you could help with this or point me to a tutorial?  Thanks, Nick

Answer (score 0):

You have to install FFMpeg in your server, so that everyone can make avail of it. If you are about to install in your local, it's quite doubtful that the process works finer or not. Instead, you can move with the hosting provider. Rely on the [web hosting](http://hioxindia.com/ffmpeg-hosting.php) provider who can support FFMpeg and provide you with SSH access.

Comment: Thanks.  I have now switched to Cirtex hosting, which includes ffmpeg and ffmpeg-PHP. I am now wondering how to write a script to convert files uploaded to a specific directory to MP3, as per the original question above.  I am wondering if you could help with this or point me to a tutorial?  Thanks, Nick